# Notation of metric "$ds^2$"

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I would like to ask about the meaning of the notation $ds^2$ as a metric, for example we have a space:
$$H=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \mid x_1^2+x^2-x^3=-1\}$$ and such that the parametrization is:
\begin{align}
x_1 &= R\cos(\alpha)  \\
x_2 &= R\sin(\phi)    \\
x_3 &= \cos(\alpha)\sin(\phi).
\end{align}

So what will be $dx_1^2$ in this case?

Thanks for any answer or remark.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is, strictly speaking ds that is the metric, not $ds^2$.

Second, do you mean $x_1^2+ x_2^2- x_3^3= -1$?

With that parameterization $x_1^2+ x_2^2-x_3^2 =R^2\cos^2(a) +R^2\sin^2(\phi) -\cos^3(a)\sin^3(\phi)$, how is that equal to $-1$ for all $a$ and $\phi$?

Comment: Your "answer" is merely a "comment".